# How Can I get QR code result to TextView?

Tags: android, zxing

I try to get QR code result to textView.
Although the camera is functioning the scan process is not supporting,although the function is inappropriate .an error message is not being display... What I do for that?

This is my QrActivity.....

---

```
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;




public class QrActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {


    /**
     * QR code declaration
     */

    Button btnscan, btnSearch;
    static TextView lblSearch;





    @Override
    protected
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);

        btnscan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscan);
        btnscan.setClickable(false);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setClickable(false);
        lblSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSearch);




        final Activity activity = this;
        btnscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public
            void onClick(View v) {
                btnscan.setClickable(true);
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();


            }


        });


    }

    /**
     * ---------------------------------------------------- QR code ----------------------------------------------------------
     */


    @Override
    protected
    void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (result != null) {

            if (result.getContents() == null) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                /**
                 * Qr code result
                 * */
                lblSearch.setText(result.getContents());

                // Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    /**
     *  -----------------------------------------QR scan-- Finished-------------------------------------*
     * */
```

Comment: Did you check the result return null or not?

Comment: And make sure that you take the camera permission

Comment: Yes I took camera permission also,

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

Comment: Result return is null

Comment: From API version 23 you need to take runtime permission beside manifest

Comment: Sorry I took two camera permission including    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" /> , .... That's why It's not working.

Comment: So all is ok now?